# OSError: Subprocess <subprocess.Popen object at 0x7fb398d26610> closed unexpectedly [java -Xmx2048m -jar /LIUM_SpkDiarization-4.7.jar

Tags: python, ubuntu, voice-recognition, voice

I am trying to implement "speaker diarization" using [voiceid](https://code.google.com/archive/p/voiceid/) on Ubuntu 16.04. I am facing a couple of issues when I try to add model to db using db.add_model(). The wiki document of [VoiceID](https://code.google.com/archive/p/voiceid/wikis/UsingLibrary.wiki) says that even if no model is added, it still gives output with unknown identifier. I tried implementing that but again the similar error.

The code is the following :

```
from voiceid.sr import Voiceid
from voiceid.db import GMMVoiceDB

db = GMMVoiceDB('db_voice')

db.add_model('speaker1','speaker_one')

v = Voiceid(db,'convo1.mp3')

v.extract_speakers()

for c in v.get_clusters():
    cluster = v.get_cluster(c)
    print cluster
    cluster.print_segments()
```

The error i get for add_model() step is the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "voiceid1.py", line 6, in 
db.add_model('speaker1','speaker_one')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/voiceid/db.py", line 187, in add_model
fm.build_gmm(basefilename, identifier)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/voiceid/fm.py", line 315, in build_gmm
diarization_standard(filebasename)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/voiceid/fm.py", line 524, in diarization_standard
+ filebasename)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/voiceid/utils.py", line 79, in start_subprocess
raise err
OSError: Subprocess <subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f9564d80710> closed unexpectedly [java -Xmx2048m -jar /usr/local/share/voiceid/LIUM_SpkDiarization-4.7.jar fr.lium.spkDiarization.system.Diarization --fInputMask=%s.wav --sOutputMask=%s.seg --doCEClustering /home/vikas/python_codes/diarize/speaker1]
```

The error when I get for v.extract_speakers() step is the following :

```
converting_file
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "voiceid1.py", line 10, in 
v.extract_speakers()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/voiceid/sr.py", line 988, in extract_speakers
self._to_wav()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/voiceid/sr.py", line 697, in _to_wav
fname = fm.file2wav(self.get_filename())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/voiceid/fm.py", line 84, in file2wav
+ "wavenc ! filesink location=" + name + ".wav ")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/voiceid/utils.py", line 79, in start_subprocess
raise err
OSError: Subprocess <subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f85f32e17d0> closed unexpectedly [gst-launch filesrc location='convo1.mp3' ! decodebin ! audioresample ! 'audio/x-raw-int,rate=16000' ! audioconvert ! 'audio/x-raw-int,rate=16000,depth=16,signed=true,channels=1' !wavenc ! filesink location=convo1.wav ]
```

I use java version "1.8.0_101". Python 2.7.12.

I even ran the jar file out of Python on terminal and the output I got is the following :

```
info[info] ======================================================
info[program] name = Diarization
info[info] ------------------------------------------------------
info[show] [options] show
info[ParameterFeature-Input] --fInputMask Features input mask = %s.mfcc
info[ParameterFeature-Input] --fInputDesc Features info (type[,s:e:ds:de:dds:dde,dim,c:r:wSize:method]) = audio2sphinx,1:1:0:0:0:0,13,0:0:0:0
info[ParameterFeature-Input] type [sphinx,spro4,htk,gztxt,audio2sphinx] = audio2sphinx (4)
info[ParameterFeature-Input] static [0=not present,1=present ,3=to be removed] = 1
info[ParameterFeature-Input] energy [0,1,3] = 1
info[ParameterFeature-Input] delta [0,1,2=computed on the fly,3] = 0
info[ParameterFeature-Input] delta energy [0,1,2=computed on the fly,3] = 0
info[ParameterFeature-Input] delta delta [0,1,2,3] = 0
info[ParameterFeature-Input] delta delta energy [0,1,2,3] = 0
info[ParameterFeature-Input] file dim = 13
info[ParameterFeature-Input] normalization, center [0,1] = 0
info[ParameterFeature-Input] normalization, reduce [0,1] = 0
info[ParameterFeature-Input] normalization, window size = 0
info[ParameterFeature-Input] normalization, method [0 (segment), 1 (cluster), 2 (sliding), 3 (warping)] =0
info[ParameterFeature-Input] --fInputMemoryOccupationRate memory occupation rate of the feature in the java virtual machine = 0.8
info[info] ------------------------------------------------------
info[ParameterSegmentationFile-Input] --sInputMask segmentation mask =
info[ParameterSegmentationFile-Input ([seg,bck,ctl,saus.seg,seg.xml,media.xml],[ISO-8859-1,UTF8])] --sInputFormat segmentation format = seg,ISO-8859-1
info[ParameterSegmentationFile-Input2] --sInput2Mask segmentation mask =
info[ParameterSegmentationFile-Input2 ([seg,bck,ctl,saus.seg,seg.xml,media.xml],[ISO-8859-1,UTF8])] --sInput2Format segmentation format = seg,ISO-8859-1
info[ParameterSegmentationFile-Output] --sOutputMask segmentation mask = %s.out.seg
info[ParameterSegmentationFile-Output ([seg,bck,ctl,saus.seg,seg.xml,media.xml],[ISO-8859-1,UTF8])] --sOutputFormat segmentation format = seg,ISO-8859-1
info[info] ------------------------------------------------------
info[ParameterSystem] --system [baseline,10s]= baseline
info[ParameterSystem] --doCEClustering = false
info[ParameterSystem] --doTuning = false
info[ParameterSystem] --thresholds = l=2.0, h=3.0, d=250.0, c=1.7:5.0
info[ParameterSystem] --saveAllStep = false
info[ParameterSystem] --loadInputSegmentation = false
info[info] ------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you for your help in advance.